# Adding to NSArray inside of for loop causes a duplication?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to grab some database values from firebase however when I attempt to store these values in an NSArray it writes the first value then it overwrites it with a new value and duplicates that value again, I have been trying for at least an hour and a half to try to get past this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Code:

```
databaseContents = [NSArray new];
    
FIRDatabaseReference *ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];

[[ref child:@"posts"] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
    for (FIRDataSnapshot *children in snapshot.children) {
        NSDictionary *snapshotAsDict = [children value];
        NSString *postTitle = [snapshotAsDict valueForKey:@"Title"];
        NSString *postBody = [snapshotAsDict valueForKey:@"Body"];
        Post *post = [[Post alloc] initWithPostTitle:postTitle initWithPostBody:postBody];
       // [databaseContents addObject:post];
        databaseContents = [databaseContents arrayByAddingObject:post];
        for (post in databaseContents) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [post getPostBody]);
        }
    }
    
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}];
```

JSON:

```
{
    "posts": {
        "127k9": {
            "Body": "This is another post",
            "Title": "Test"
        },
        "17a32b": {
            "Body": "This is a post from the database, you did it!",
            "Title": "Well Done!"
        }
    }
}
```

Result from NSLog:

```
2020-07-04 02:35:00.970071+0100 AppName [27829:919355] This is value1
2020-07-04 02:35:00.970390+0100 AppName [27829:919355] This is value2
2020-07-04 02:35:00.970557+0100 AppName[27829:919355] This is value2
```

Comment: Hey Reece. Can you explain what about that output is unexpected? Also note that we can't see you database, so if the output is related to that, you'll want to add the JSON at `posts` (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Hello it all seems good on the database side, It's just on the iOS side, specifically when I append it to a list. I don't think I was descriptive enough on what I am trying to do in the question. Here is the json `{
  "posts" : {
    "127k9" : {
      "Body" : "This is another post",
      "Title" : "Test"
    },
    "17a32b" : {
      "Body" : "This is a post from the database, you did it!",
      "Title" : "Well Done!"
    }
  }
}` And I am trying to put the body and titles from both of the posts into an NSArray using a custom object called Post.

Comment: Thanks for that. The logs in no way match the JSON now though, so it's hard to say what's going on, nor what you expect this to output.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with an NSMutableArray instead.

You actually rewrite the whole array by adding an object to a copy of the array which is initiated directly above.

which makes it simple then, so..

```
[databaseContents addObject:post];
```

or place your `[NSArray new]` inside the block before the for loop